# How to clear local storage when session cookie expires in laravel and vue app

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a Vue app within a Laravel app. On logging in a user is issued authenticated session cookie by Laravel and after that, I set authenticated to true in the local storage `localStorage.setItem("authenticated", "true")`. When the session expires `authenticated is still true.` How can I remove the key when the session expires?

Comment: Do you know how long your sessions last for? You will likely have to work out when the session has expired and set authenticated to false.  You store expiry timestamp alongside authenticated then check is from your js.

Comment: @EdenWebStudio To my understanding, Laravel session by default expires only when it stays idle for 120min. Assuming it was expiring after an hour, how would you go about it? I think that can help in trying to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check session()->get("session_name") in your controller.

You can use this code below, just add in your created() or mounted() option

Check if session expired or not from API and change your localStorage key value;

```
<script>
export default {
 mounted() {
  fetch('http://yourserver.com/checkSession').then(async response => {
  const status = await response.json();
if(!status.session) {
localStorage.setItem("authenticated", "false")
}
})
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the solution. I wonder how to get the key. I tried to pass key name as laravel_session didn't work. Tried to `dd(session()->all())` and this is the output `array:3 [▼
  "_token" => "vEtr3gVu0CL7Jir1juzK9GNwXN7c2Lz35Z5n1ghf"
  "_flash" => array:2 [▶]
  "login_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d" => 5
]`

Comment: Could you show how to assign sessions to the user? `login_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d` is it your session variable? In Laravel, I usually use `$request->session()->put(['key' => 'value']);` and when getting session key: `$request->session()->get('key');`

Comment: I'm not assigning the sessions. It's Laravel's built-in cookie-based session authentication service.